# Instructions in the wrong order in a very simple program

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm beginning to learn C. As I'm usually coding with JAVA, I had chosen to use the IDE Eclipse and not Code:: Blocks. And I'm already experimenting a bug with that very simple program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int number=0;

    printf("Type a number :\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("You typed %d",number);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run, I'm expecting something like :

> Type a number
>    (...) I type my number
>   You typed xxx

But, that's not what I get. When I compile and run, nothing appears in the console. And when I type a number and press "Enter", I finally get :

> Type a number
>   You typed xxx

What's wrong ? Why do the instructions are not executed in the expected order? Is it a problem with Eclipse?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Without looking into technicalities, yes, this is a problem with the IDE.

Comment: the program looks fine. Try running it from console and see if you get the correct behaviour.

Comment: If you use linux you can compile using command: `gcc main.c -o exec` and run `./exec`, you will exclude problem with IDE.

Comment: Ok, I just copied / pasted the program in Code::Blocks and it works like a charm. So, the problem seems to be with Eclipse. Eclipse is a serious IDE. They developped a plug-in for C/C++ and there is a bug with such a simple program ??? It's a bit unbelievable...

Comment: The program doesn't print 'xxx', it prints a number. What number does it print when you run it in Eclipse? Have you typed that number before?

Comment: Please try to use `\r\n` instead of `\n` and see if it helps, some consoles look for special end of lines to flush the buffer to screen, or alternatively you can try `fflush(stdout)` after each printf

Comment: @n.m. Of course, it don't print "xxx" but the number I typed before.

Comment: @hessamhedieh Ok, it works with fflush(stdout). Can you explain me why do I need this instruction ?

Comment: When you ask questions please try sticking to exact facts. So you have typed a number, then started your program. Where do you think that number went?

Comment: @n.m. so how would you type it ? You would write : I expect "the_number_I_have_typed_with_my_fingers_on_the_keyboard_of_the_computer" ?

Comment: I would say it like that: *I have typed the number 42 then started my program, and it didn't wait for me to type another number but printed "You typed 42"*. Why would I replace the actual number with long abd meaningless words?

Comment: If that was the actual sequence of events of course. I think I misunderstood what you have said and that's nit what has actually happened. Sorry.

Comment: @n.m : It's ok. I'll try to write more clear explanations next time.  And I thank you to have had an interest for my question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bug with Eclipse.

hessamhedieh's answer helped me to find it out and, after looking for the words

> "Eclipse, scanff fflush(stdout)"

in google, I found many posts about this [bug still unsolved](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354098).